# Refinement Webpart with terms and child terms

Tags: 2013, search, managed-metadata, search-results, term-store

I'm trying to build a news archive for a intranet. A single news article has a managed metadata column named News Categories and points to a termset named News Categories. In that column the editors can tag the news article with different groups/locations etc.

In the news archive I want to have a refinement web part (RWP) that lists these groups/locations and their child terms.

How can I achieve this when I only have one column? I've tried use property mapping but can only map the column and the RWP lists all terms in my termset (not the structure I want).

So, this is an example of my termset:

```
#News Categories
 -Group
   *Group A
   *Group B
   *Group C
 -Location
   *Sweden
   *GB
   *Germany
 -Function
   *Function A
   *Function B
   *Function C
```

And in my RWP I want the same structure. When I click on the term "Sweden" the "Pages search WP" should list all news that are taged with Sweden.

EDIT: 
I know one solution of this problem. That is to create (in this example case) three new fields and an Item update event receiver that calculates the value of our News Categories column and sets the belonging value to each of the new columns. Then create property mappings for the three new columns. Is this the right way to do this? Seems like a strange solution for a common(?) problem. Here is that solution: [Refinement panel does not implement hierarchy of managed metadata](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76866/refinement-panel-does-not-implement-hierarchy-of-managed-metadata)